# How to map entity to table in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, mapping, spring-data-jdbc

In Spring Data JPA we can map an entity to a specific table by using `@Table` annotation where we can specify schema and name.

But Spring Data JDBC uses a `NamingStrategy` to map an entity to a table name by converting the entities class name. For example, if we have the entity class named `MetricValue` then the table should be named `metricvalue` in default schema. But I need to map `MetricValue` to the `metric_value` table in `app` schema.

Is there any way to override this mapping by annotation or any other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The naming behavior is defined by the default implementation of the interface `NamingStrategy`

From [reference documentation, section 4.4.3 of version 1.0.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.naming-strategy):

> When you use the standard implementations of CrudRepository that Spring Data 
>   JDBC provides, they expect a certain table structure. You can tweak that by 
>   providing a NamingStrategy in your application context.

The default implementation has [the following behavior (from javadoc version 1.0.2)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/relational/core/mapping/NamingStrategy.html):

> Defaults to no schema, table name based on Class and column name based on 
>   RelationalPersistentProperty with name parts of both separated by '_'.

So create a bean which implements `NamingStrategy` in register it in your application context.

This is an example from @keddok comment:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class MetricStoreRepositoryConfig extends JdbcConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    NamingStrategy namingStrategy() {
        return new NamingStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String getSchema() {
                return "metric";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, @Kartoch! Seems this approach is valid and i was able to go further. Unfortunately i stuck into other problem and can't verify completness of this solution. I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: UPDATE. Yes, `NamingStrategy` bean did his job well.

Comment: @keddok could you put an example as a new answer ?

Comment: pushed a simple boot application using `NamingStrategy` configuration for schema: https://github.com/keddok/sandbox/tree/master/spring-data-jdbc

Answer (score 12):

[Spring Data JDBC has it's own `@Table` annotation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/master/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/mapping/Table.java) and also an [`@Column`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/master/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/mapping/Column.java) one.

You just add the annotation to your entity and specify the name as the value of the annotation.

To give some examples:

```
@Table("entity") 
class MyEntity {

    private @Column("last_name") String name;

    @Column(value = "entity_id", keyColumn = "entity_index") 
    private List<SomeOtherEntity> someList;
}
```

This will read and write `MyEntity` into/from the table `entity` instead of the default `my_entity`. 
The attribute `name` will get stored in the column `last_name`.
And the columns for backreferencing from the `some_other_entity` to `entity` will be named `entity_id` for the foreign key column which normally would be `entity` (the table name of the referenced table).
And the list index will be stored in `entity_index` instead of the default `entity_key`.

I created [an issue for improving the documentation](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-285).

Comment: Nice, `@Table` annotation works too! Hope this is a stable feature.

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't. It will probably see some extension and improvement (like a `name` attribute equivalent to the `value` attribute).

Comment: @JensSchauder Could you put an example as a new answer ?

Comment: @Kartoch Not sure, why I'd put an example in a separate answer, but I updated the answer with an example demonstrating the use of the `@Table` and `@Column` annotation.

Answer (score -4):

Use `@Table(name = "metric_value")`.

Comment: It's not JPA neither `spring-data-jpa`.